# Moving coefficient within parentheses with SED

Tags: sed

I have a text file where appears at many places multiplications like:

```
1556 * C
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
(double)(1556)*C
```

for arbitrary numbers

Comment: Is this only ever concerning multiplications of a variable called `C` with _positive integers_, and nothing else?

Comment: Is the number always before the named variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\) *\* */(double)(\1)*/g'
```

which gives the output

```
(double)(1556)*C
```